# Emit from flask server to client JavaScript not emitting to the sender

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, socket.io

I'm trying to take text from HTML form input then emit it using JavaScript and Socket to the server-side which is python flask and then emit it to everyone and update the page for everyone with a <P> tag containing this text.

It works for all clients' side except the sender, all the previous <p> tags get deleted for an unapparent reason.

**Flask Code** :

```
@socketio.on("submit channel")
def channel(data):
    ch = data["ch"]
    channels.append(ch)
    emit("channel", {"ch": ch}, broadcast=True)
```

**JavaScript Code** :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        document.querySelector('#channel').onsubmit = () => {
            const ch = document.querySelector('#ch').value;
            socket.emit('submit channel', {'ch': ch});
        };
    });
    socket.on('channel', data => {

        const p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = data.ch;
        document.querySelector('#channels').append(p);

    });
});
```

**HTML Code** :

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block head %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
messages
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div id="channels">
</div>
<hr>
<form id="channel">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Channel Name" id="ch">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4YXW.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt7m8.jpg)